# intersection points of line and object - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I marked in green one coin (green) in the coin image and I pass a line over it. How can I find the x,y points that they are intersecting?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
clc;
clear; 

I = imread('coins.png'); 
BW = im2bw(I);

BW_filled = imfill(BW,'holes');

boundaries = bwboundaries(BW_filled);  
figure,imshow(I) ;

hold on;

b = boundaries{1}; 
plot(b(:,2),b(:,1),'g','LineWidth',1);

h = imline;
myPoints = wait(h);
delete(h)  ;
x1 = round(myPoints(1,1),2);
y1 = round(myPoints(1,2),2);
x2 = round(myPoints(2,1),2);
y2 = round(myPoints(2,2),2);

%plot line
x=[x1 x2];
y=[y1 y2];
plot(x',y','r')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find intersections between the line and circle.

```
k = abs( (b(:,2)-x1) * (y2-y1) - (b(:,1)-y1) * (x2-x1) );
[~,idx] = sort(k);
scatter(b(idx(1:2),2), b(idx(1:2),1))
```

This is a simple method. It captures all points on the circle, and check each against the [line equation](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/StraightLine.shtml).

Ideally, we have `(x-x1) / (x2-x1) = (y-y1) / (y2-y1)`, or say `d = (x-x1) / (x2-x1) - (y-y1) / (y2-y1)` and then `d=0` is the ideal situation. When the point deviates from the line, `d` increases in its absolute value. Therefore, the smallest `d` refers to the point closest to the line. In this case, there should be two points, hence I'm looking for the two smallest values.

One possible problem could be accuracy. When the points on the circle are far apart from each other, it's possible that the closest two stand for the same intersection point, leaving the other one undetected. More complicated check would apply, for example picking the closest four and then distinguish. However you can avoid this by keeping point density high.

---

EDIT: added such check.

```
k = abs( (b(:,2)-x1) * (y2-y1) - (b(:,1)-y1) * (x2-x1) );
[~,idx] = sort(k);

f4x = b(idx(1:4),2);
f4y = b(idx(1:4),1);
choose = [1,2;1,3;1,4;2,3;2,4;3,4];
dist = sqrt( (f4x(choose(:,1))-f4x(choose(:,2))).^2 + ....
    (f4y(choose(:,1))-f4y(choose(:,2))).^2);
[~, idx2] = sort(dist,'descend');

px = b(idx(choose(idx2(1,:),:).'),2);
py = b(idx(choose(idx2(1,:),:).'),1);

scatter(px, py)
```

Some results

```
>> idx(1:4)

ans =

    28
   112
   113
    29

>> dist

dist =

   55.7853
   55.5428
    1.0000
    1.0000
   55.5428
   55.3173
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more sensitive? for example by adding a distance between all of these points

Comment: @user2676173 Yeah you could add a check on the relative distance between each of the first four points. Look for the first pair of two a distinguishable distance apart.

Comment: @user2916044 Yes.

Comment: I tried to change the scatter to impoint without success. why?